# "Disregard flag" flag, or following up on flag?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, flags

I just flagged a post on SO by a user who has asked three questions this week, all essentially the same, of the "plz post c0d3z" variety, and the first two of which were answered with useful information and links to further resources. This user has apparently not availed emself of the earlier answers.

Then I noticed that, according to this user's page, e is 13 years old. I thought "Hmm, maybe I/we should cut the kid some slack." I left a comment for the user and tried to re-flag the question to alert the mods of this possible extenuating circumstance, but of course it's not possible to flag a post again.

This leaves me with a two-part question:

1. What, if anything, should I do if I realize I have flagged in error? Be more careful next time? Leave a comment directed at moderators?
2. Does anyone think there should be a way to flag your earlier flag, or would this be way meta-overkill work for the mods?

(Also, I'm interested in any opinions about flagging kids in the same way one would flag adults, but this is really a separate question.)

---

<sub>Apologies if anyone is irritated by the Spivak pronouns. Feel free to edit them out.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the kid is turning 13 this year (~60% chance of that given current month), s/he has no business on StackOverflow.  https://stackexchange.com/legal "Subscriber is at least 13 years of age".

Otherwise, once the flag has gone, let it be.  Mistakes happen, and trying to fight an uphill battle for edge cases is like swatting gnats in the middle of an Indonesian forest.

Comment: That's about what I thought the answer would be. I didn't know about the age limit. Thanks for the reply, Richard.